# how to highlight current tab on Terminator

Tags: tabs, themes, terminator

I find hard to distinguish the current tab I'm working on it with Terminator:

[image: terminator-tabs]

Is there a way to highlight it?

I found some answers to this question, but most of them are old and all the ones I tried do not work anymore